# select all inputs except hidden (but with one exception)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say I have a set of inputs on a form:

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="checkbox" id="goat_1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="goat_2">
  <input type="text" id="pig_3">
  <input type="hidden" id="cow_1">
  <input type="hidden" id="chick_3">
  <input type="hidden" id="duck_5">
</form>
```

I want to select all inputs, except `type="hidden"`, but with one exception I DO want any hidden input with an id beginning with "duck". I need this all in one array so I can iterate through it.

So the first two parts are easy:

```
$("#myform").find(":input").not("[type=hidden]").each(
                                          function () { alert("do stuff"); })
```

But what about the exception?

I am looking for the cleanest way to do this (prefer one line/statement).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
$("#myform").find(":input").not("[type=hidden]:not([id^='duck'])").each(function () {
    alert("do stuff"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#myform > input').not(':hidden:not([id^=duck])').each(function (i, e) {
    alert('This is my id: ' + e.id);
});
```

Working example in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dWYSD/2/).